# switch video after video ends and on click of a button

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I found this video slider which switches to the next slide when the video ends but I was wondering how I could implement a button or multiple buttons that switch to specific video (like jumping from video 2 to 5 for example) or a button that simply goes to the next / previous video.

Either is fine for me.

the script:

```
var video1 = document.getElementById('video1');
var video2 = document.getElementById('video2');
var video3 = document.getElementById('video3');
var video4 = document.getElementById('video4');
var video5 = document.getElementById('video5');
var video6 = document.getElementById('video6');

function imgTransition(){
    imagen1.style.opacity=0;
    video1.play();
    video1.style.opacity=1;
}
video1.onended = function(){
    video2.play();
    video1.style.opacity=0;
    video2.style.opacity=1;
}
video2.onended = function(){
    video3.play();
    video2.style.opacity=0;
    video3.style.opacity=1;
}
video3.onended = function(){
    video4.play();
    video3.style.opacity=0;
    video4.style.opacity=1;
}
video4.onended = function(){
    video5.play();
    video4.style.opacity=0;
    video5.style.opacity=1;
}
video5.onended = function(){
    video6.play();
    video5.style.opacity=0;
    video6.style.opacity=1;
}
video6.onended = function(){
    video1.play();
    video6.style.opacity=0;
    video1.style.opacity=1;
}
```

I already tried to add a button that tries to execute the specific function but it didn't quite work.

adding a video in HTML:

```
</video>
        <video muted id="video1" class="video1">
        <source src="../images/comp_1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Delegate (not tested)

---

```
let cnt = 0;
const container = document.getElementById("videoContainer");
const videos = container.querySelectorAll("video");
const next = num => {
  num = num || ++cnt;
  if (cnt>videos.length) cnt = 0; // wrap
  if (num>0) videos[nums-1].style.opacity=0;
    videos[num].style.opacity=1;
    videos[num].play();
}; 
container.addEventListener("ended", next);

document.getElementById("next").addEventListener("click",next)
```

The above code would lend itself easily to ONE player, where you change

```
videos[num].play();
```

to

```
video.src=videoArray[num].src
video.play()
```

Comment: would it look something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/HcJanni/8msk3gjo/)?

Comment: thank you! I'll fiddle around with it a little bit and see if I can get it to work :)

Comment: @hcjanni Here is a corrected (but not playing) version with multiple video tags: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/9naf2c36/ - you need more code to have only one video tag and you need to create the video array

Answer (score 0):

You could put video1...6 in an object, and on button click do something like this:
Iterate over the object until you find your currently active (opacity=1) video, and set its opacity=0 and stop the player. For the next element in the videos object, set the opacity=1 and play it.

Alternatively you could store the video urls in an object and switch the player's src, instead of having multiple players.
`document.getElementById('#player').src = newSourceURL`

Comment: having only one player is probably my best option to also optimize the website. How do I do that though?

Comment: you can access the .src property of the player easily. mplungjan's code should do the trick